# Tweet using twitter4j with photo

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to tweet along with photo using tweeter4j? I know this can be done by appending image url in the message body. Doing this does not give effect of see photo on tweeter. My photo is on the server and not on local machine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I only used the sharing part from this tutorial http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/sharing-text-image-in-twitter-android-example/

and used the login and authentication part from this tutorial http://hintdesk.com/how-to-tweet-in-twitter-within-android-client/

I've achieved exactly what you want using those two tutorials a few mins ago.

**edit**

if you are using universal-image-loader for loading images. then your images are cached and you don't need to re-download them (as in the first link) to post to Twitter.
you can use

```
StatusUpdate st = new StatusUpdate("text");

st.setMedia(DiscCacheUtil.findInCache(IMAGE_URL, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache()));
```